# HTML2PDF ,Font Size of pdf very small on printing the pdf

Tags: angular, typescript, html2pdf

var opt = {
margin: 1,
filename: '1099PdfData.pdf',
image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: a0, orientation: 'l'}
};

I am using this parameter to convert HTML to PDF but when printing AO page its very small text how could I increase the text size . Can anyone guide for this

Comment: 28 point where ?.  In your suggested code

Comment: means I have to  increase the size of text in HTML par right , for Ao the test size small like I am converting htmltoPDF

Comment: When I awil print that image its showing very small text

Answer (score 0):

**This works with me, also this snippet can print multiple pages**

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) { }

captureScreen() {
    const data = this.document.getElementById('content');

    html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
      const imgWidth = 285; // any width
      const imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;

      const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
      let pdf = new jspdf('l', 'mm', 'a4'); // config
      const position = 0;

      pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)
      pdf.save('capture.pdf'); // file name
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: getting this error fter using this

Comment: inject Document  such as                                               
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) { }